# Как записать sqlite таблицу в таблицу docx при помощи Python

Tags: python, sqlite

Я столкнулся с проблемой, я не знаю как записывать sqlite таблицы в  таблицы docx.

Comment: Разбейте задачу на части: как получить данные из БД; как записать данные в docx. Какая часть у вас не получается? Что вы пытались сделать?